# How to keep redux-form submission errors after switching from a wizard-form "piece" to another?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a wizard form that is separated in 4 different routes. The user can submit the form on any of the 4 wizard steps.

When I receive the field errors from the server, I put them on redux-store using "stopSubmit" action creator (tried using setSubmitFailed too, but I didn't get the difference it made). After that dispatch, the field errors are shown correctly on every field.

However, when I switch to any of the other steps/pages, the "@@redux-form/INITIALIZE" action occurs automatically and all the submission errors I put before are deleted from the store.

How can I keep them when switching routes/forms?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for `destroyOnUnmount: false`.

> Specify the destroyOnUnmount: false flag to preserve form data across form component unmounts.

```
export default reduxForm({
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(Form)
```

---

Also you may pass `forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true`, because here's what the docs says:

> Whether or not to force unregistration of fields -- use in conjunction with destroyOnUnmount. Useful for wizard-type forms where you want to destroy fields as they unmount, but not the form's state. Defaults to false, as forms are normally unregistered on unmount.

Here's a [complete example](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/wizard/), where the errors are kept across the different wizard forms (steps).

Comment: I actually have both flags set the way you explained, but the submission errors are still being lost when I change the form component that is being shown. I also have initialValues being set their mapStateToProps.

By checking the redux dev tools I saw that the action "@@redux-form/INITIALIZE" happens when I switch to a form page and this action is the one that simply deletes my submission errors.

Comment: It's strange! Did you check the [complete wizard example](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/wizard/) I mentioned? There, if you successfully submit the step 1, after that submit the step 2 with failures and the errors are shown, go back to step 1, and finally go again to step 2, then the errors are still kept. I guess you want to achieve the same behavior. Therefore please follow the example. If it doesn't help you - please provide a working code example (jsfiddle, sandbox), that will help us to support you. Good luck! :)